Hide Records of specific record type in global search
We need users to avoid seeing records in global search or view. are there any possible ways to do this

If a user can see the record, and the global search has indexed that record, there's no way to prevent those results from showing up in global search.

You can hide custom object records from search. On standard objects like Account this setting is not available. Then if they can see the Account, the Account will show up in search.

